# How to run custom script when xcode bots failed

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

I have added post-action script for Archive phase of building. In this script UIAutomation test are run. When tests pass or not an appropriate information is sent to jenkis server.
The problem is when build failed because of compilation erros. Then post-action script is not running and jenkins server will not receive any information. How to run custom script when bots failed during compilation ?
I have found in xCode -> Preferences -> Behaviours bots section. There is a place to select a script when build fails, but I can't select any file. There is better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode if you select xCode->Preference->Behaviors bot section and you select "Fail", in the window on the right check off "Run" and then double click on the "Choose Script..." drop down menu. A window to select a script should come up.

Comment: It works when you compile a code on your xcode. When compilation is started by bots after the code commits it doesn't work ;/

Comment: Ok I connect xcode with server and it works ! It was very useful: http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/12/08/generate-beautiful-code-documentation-with-simple-shortcut-using-appledoc-xcode-custom-behaviours-applescript/